# How to make entire form invalid with jquery.validate plugin?

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I want to make an entire form invalid (not just a specific field) when something happens (response from server or impossibility to continue because of external conditions).

My example is that the user shouldn't be able to submit the form when it is waiting for an AJAX response from the server. All subsequent fields are disabled, until the AJAX comes back, so the form is valid, which allows the user to submit it.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="input1" required="required">
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
    </select>
    <select name="input2" id="input2" disabled="disabled" required="required">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="foo">Foo</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<p></p>
<p>Fake response from server
    <button id="response">Fake</button>
</p>
```

JS:

```
var waitingForServer;

waitingForServer = true;

$('form').validate();

$('#response').on('click', function() {
  waitingForServer = false;
  return $('#input2').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

<kbd>[See live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zinkkrysty/zkDVW/)</kbd>

How do I prevent the user from submitting the form until the AJAX request has completed?

Answer (score 0):

It worked with adding a on submit handler on the form:

```
$('form').on('submit', function (evt) {
    if (waitingForServer) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

<kbd>[New live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zinkkrysty/zkDVW/1/)</kbd>

The only problem I see is not knowing if this is consistent (whether the jquery.validate handler sometimes fires before this one or not).

I'm open to accepting better answers of course.

Comment: This will not work well.  Consider using the callback functions built into the plugin... `submitHandler` and `invalidHandler`, which fire when the form is valid (former) or invalid (latter) whenever you click the button.

Answer (score 0):

**Quote OP:**

> *"How do I prevent that from happenning?"*

I'm not really sure what you're mean by this as your entire question is somewhat unclear.

However, when I submit forms with `ajax()`, to prevent further interactions, I immediately remove the form from the page, show a spinner animation, and then display a confirmation message after the server responds.  I do all of this from within the `submitHandler` function built into the plugin.

```
$('#myform').validate({
    // rules & options,
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $('#formWrapper').hide();         // make the form disappear
        $('#spinner').show();             // show the animated spinner
        $.ajax({                          // submit the form via ajax
            url: 'path-to-server',        // url to submit to
            data: $(form).serialize(),    // serialized form data
            success: function(msg) {      // response from server
                $('#message').html(msg);  // load message into hidden div
                $('#spinner').hide();     // hide the animated spinner
                $('#message').show();     // show the response message
            }
        });
        return false;                     // blocks default form action when using ajax
    }
});
```

This is just an example.  You can easily modify it to...

- dim out the form container
- cover the form container with a semi-transparent object so you cannot access the controls
- use animations, wipes, slides, or fades
- etc. or do any actions following these basic steps above

Comment: Thanks. I made my question more clear. I'll try this out, and let you know if it suits my purpose.